5th Dimension in a Bell Science series film short about innovators
I remember seeing a film short (~60 min) in a classroom setting in the 1970s that featured the musical group The 5th Dimension in between segments of a presentation on American innovators. One of the segments I remember showed Korcyk Ziolkowski and his quest to sculpt the Crazy Horse monument in South Dakota. 
I also checked out the list of Bell Science series films, which I thought this would have been a part of. However, none of the titles applies: Alphabet Conspiracy, Gateway to the Mind, Strange Case of the Cosmic Rays, Hemo the Magnificent, Our Mr. Sun, The Thread of Life, The Unchained Goddess, The Restless Sea, About Time.
Does anyone remember this short? Better, the title and producer of the film?

How about 1970's "It Couldn't Be Done", with Lee Marvin as the narrator and the 5th Dimension as "Themselves":

"This program is a kaleidoscopic preview of a most exciting,
  entertaining, and educational television special, IT COULDN'T BE DONE,
  which the Bell System will sponsor on Thursday evening, April 2 at
  7:30 pm (EST)." 
This quote is from the offical program guide for the
  telecast. The program covered the building of the Hoover Dam, the
  Transcontinental Railway without power tools or dynamite, Mount
  Washington Cog Railroad, Georgia's Stone Mountain sculpture (largest
  in world), Chief Crazy Horse (as large as the four Mount Rushmore
  heads combined), ...

Here's the IMDB link.

In 1977, there was a CBS "60-Minutes" TV special about Korcyk and his 'quest'.
I could not access the video, but could this be the one?
http://www.cbsnews.com/videos/crazy-horse-korczak

the Crazy Horse doc was just one part of an hour long documentary, and I am fairly sure 60 minutes would not use the 5th Dimension in their segment. But it's always nice to know about more material on Mr. Z.
